LAN8742 Ethernet PHY link down error at Oryx CycloneTCP SNMP Agent Demo
I am using CycloneTCP stack on CubeIDE. I am using Stm32f746NGH6 discovery board to test SNMP Agent Demo. I double checked my Ethernet GPIO pins, clock and systemclk frequencies for RMII_REF_CLK, MAC address and Ethernet IP settings. Everything looks normal and as it should be.
My problem is that I ping my device and got no response. When I sent OID request on SNMP NMS tester side I got no response. While looking for the source of the error in hardware debug, I observed that there was an error in Ethernet LAN8742 Phy layer.
This is where the program gets stuck  netTask(); in the hardware debug phase.
 while (1)
  {
     //Handle TCP/IP events
     netTask();
     //Handle SNMP agent events
     snmpAgentTask(&snmpAgentContext);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

This is where I added the program code for the ethernet connection section.
  /* Initialize TCP/IP stack */
  error = netInit();
  if (error) {
      TRACE_ERROR("Failed to initialize TCP/IP stack! Error: %d\r\n", error);
      return error;
  }

  //Configure the first Ethernet interface
  interface = &netInterface[0];

  //Set interface name
  netSetInterfaceName(interface, "eth0");
  //Set host name
  netSetHostname(interface, "tcpdemo");
  //Select the relevant network adapter
  netSetDriver(interface, &stm32f7xxEthDriver);


  // Check if the NIC driver is assigned correctly
  if (interface->nicDriver == NULL) {
      printf("Error: NIC driver assignment failed!\r\n");
      return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;  // Or return a suitable error code
  } else {
      printf("NIC driver assigned successfully.\r\n");
  }

  //Select the relevant PHY driver
  netSetPhyDriver(interface, &lan8742PhyDriver);

  // Check if the PHY driver is assigned correctly
  if (interface->phyDriver == NULL) {
      printf("Error: PHY driver assignment failed!\r\n");
      return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;  // Or return a suitable error code
  } else {
      printf("PHY driver assigned successfully.\r\n");
  }
  //Set host MAC address
  macStringToAddr(APP_MAC_ADDR, &macAddr);
  netSetMacAddr(interface, &macAddr);

  /* Configure network interface */
  printf("Configuring Ethernet interface...\r\n");
  TRACE_INFO("**********************************\r\n");
  error = netConfigInterface(interface);
  if (error) {
      TRACE_ERROR("Failed to configure interface %s! Error: %d\r\n", interface->name, error);
      return error;
  } else {
      printf("Interface configured successfully.\r\n");
  }

In addition, my serial monitor output is as follows;
NIC driver assigned successfully.
PHY driver assigned successfully.
Configuring Ethernet interface...
**********************************
Interface configured successfully.
Checking Ethernet link status...

**********************************

Manual PHY Register Read: 0x00007809
Ethernet link is down. Check cable and connections.
Ethernet link status checked.
Setting static IP configuration...
Ethernet configuration complete.

**********************************
LAN8742_ISR value: 0x0090
LAN8742_BMSR value: 0x7809
Link is down.

As a result of the printfs I added to the lan8742EventHandler function in drivers/phy/lan8742_driver.h, I observed that my code ended up here:
interface->linkState = FALSE;
printf(“Link is down.\r\n”);

How can I debug and resolve this connection issue?
